# How do I input a current balance in a cell from a running balance that will be updated frequently?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I know I'm not accurately explaining that but here's a sample spreadsheet of what I mean:

[image: Link to spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options.
Note that it is advisable to treat the opening balance as a transaction in the "Credits/Deposits" column

**Assumption** - "Total" is Column G

**Option #1:**
Enter these formulas in the nominated cells

- `=F2` - enter in Cell G2.
- `=G2-E3+F3` - enter in Cell G3. Then copy cell down as many rows as necessary

**Option#2:**

- Enter this formula in cell G2

`=ArrayFormula(if(len(B2:B),(SUMIF(ROW(F2:F),"<="&ROW(F2:F),F2:F)-SUMIF(ROW(E2:E),"<="&ROW(E2:E),E2:E)),))`

This will automatically update the Total as transactions are added.